# Evaluating a Fourier integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

Is it possible to evaluate the following integral?

$$\int \frac{(x-x_0) \: dx \: dy \: e^{i k_x x + i k_y y}}{((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+4 h^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$

As a first try, I evaluated

```
Integrate[Exp[I ky y]/(A + (y - y0)^2)^(5/2), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

However, it didn't work.

Any answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at FourierTransform?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to approach this sort of thing: start simple and make it more complex as you go:

```
FourierTransform[1/t^2, t, w]
```

returns an answer just fine. So make it more complicated:

```
FourierTransform[1/(t - t0^2), t, w]
```

also works. Increase complexity:

```
FourierTransform[1/(a + (t - t0^2)), t, w]
```

still OK. Once more:

```
FourierTransform[1/(a + (t - t0^2))^(5/2), t, w]
```

wait a while, and you'll get an answer. Now your turn, but in 2D (still with FourierTransform).